# getProtocol() in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

Is there a way I can get the protocol (http or https) in Vaadin? I can get the host and the port, but I also need the protocol.

```
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

[...]

UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getHost();
UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getPort();
```

So I need something like:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getProtocol();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there :-)

`System.out.println("Scheme=[" + Page.getCurrent().getLocation().getScheme() + "]");`

> Scheme=[http]

---

Adding more options as per the discusstion with Andre below:

```
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {

    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Location scheme=[" + Page.getCurrent().getLocation().getScheme() + "]");
        System.out.println("Web browser isSecureConnection=[" + Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser().isSecureConnection() + "]");
        System.out.println("Request isSecure=[" + request.isSecure()+"]");
    }
}
```

> Location scheme=[http] 
>   Web browser isSecureConnection=[false] 
>   Request isSecure=[false]

Comment: Depnding on what you need to know, there is also a isSecure() property which tells you about http/s

Comment: @AndréSchild Can you share a code sample? The `URI` object returned by the `getLocation()` method doesn't seem to expose such a method.

Comment: @AndréSchild maybe `Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser().isSecureConnection()`?

Comment: Thanks! getScheme() did it for me. :)